# Expected Primary expression before int inside a function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, void

I am very aware that a lot of the formatting of this code is likely to be completely wrong. I am attempting to create a function GenPathByNumber which itself calls a function Binary. The GenPathBynumber attempts to (for integer x values from 0 through to 2^N - 1) create an array Path for each x value, with entries corresponding to each digit of x's binary representation. Binary converts each x to its binary reresentation, and GenPathByNumber puts binary through a loop.
When trying to build this, the logs keep saying "Expected Primary expression before int" for the Binary function (line 10 in the code below). Please can someone tell me what the problem(s) are?

```
void GenPathByNumber(int x,int N,int *Path)
{
    //Create the array Path of length N, with all entries set to 0
    Path[N] = {0};
    //runs a for loop of all x values up to 2^N - 1
    //and generates a binary path corresponding to each number
    // of length N, then stores each digit of this in array Path.
    for (int x = 0; x < pow(2,N)-1; x++)
    {
     binary(int x, int* Path);
    }
}

void binary(int x, int* Path) {
    if (x == 0) {
        printf("%s\n", Path);
    } else {
        Path[x-1]='0';
        binary(x-1);
        Path[x-1] = '1';
        binary(x-1);
            }
    }
```

Comment: `Path[N] = {0}` does not create an array of size N with all values equal to zero in the context shown.  When calling a function, you do not specify the types, like you did inside your `for` loop... In your `binary` function, you have a recursive call that is missing the second parameter ... You are trying to use `printf` to print an array of integers? There are a lot or errors here. I'd recommend going back to your notes / book / reference material.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the for loop in `GenPathByNumber` you have:

```
for (int x = 0; x < pow(2,N)-1; x++)
{
   binary(int x, int* Path);
}
```

You don't need the argument type specifiers when you call a function, only when you define it. Remove those and the error goes away.

```
binary(x, Path);
```

You have other errors inside the `binary` function where you're calling it with only one argument, like `binary(x - 1);`. You probably mean to provide `Path` in those calls as well.